# Rewriting a**2 + ab + c in FORTH

Tags: forth

Chapter 2 Problem 4 of [Starting FORTH](http://www.forth.com/starting-forth/) ([online here](https://www.forth.com/starting-forth/2-stack-manipulation-operators-arithmetic/#Problems_Chapter_2)) asks you to write a definition for

```
a**2 + ab + c  ( c a b -- result )
```

The answer key says

```
: 2-4 OVER + * + ;
```

How is that the case, let's assume a=1, b=2, c=3

```
3 1 2  ok
OVER .s <4> 3 1 2 1  ok
+ .s <3> 3 1 3  ok
* .s <2> 3 3  ok
+ .s <1> 6  ok
```

Comment: It looks fine. The key here is that the answer calculates it like this: `a(a+b) +c` which is in fact `over + * +`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works because as mentioned in the comments, I was being math-stupid.

I was seeing

```
OVER .s <4> 3 1 2 1  ok
+ .s <3> 3 1 3  ok
```

And being thrown for a loop. The problem is

```
a**2 + ab + c  ( c a b -- result )
```

is the same as

```
a(a+b) + c  ( c a b -- result )
```

which is the same as

```
c + a(a+b)  ( c a b -- result )
```

Which is essentially what they're doing. They move the forms around a bit

```
c + a(a+b)
c + a(b+a)
```

You see that in the stack, which gets rearranged to this...

```
c a b
c a b a  -- after over
```

Then they just run

```
c a b a + * +
```

Clever, thanks to [Mateusz Piotrowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4694621/mateusz-piotrowski) for pointing it out in the comments.

Comment: I suspect @Mateusz answered the question.  c-: